# Singleton property always null in Xamarin.iOS binding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

I followed the documentation and was successful in building a Xamarin.iOS binding for a third party framework. I used Objective Sharpie to generate my binding code and then made some minor changes to remove verify attributes, add class names etc. My project builds fine.

When I call the singleton instance of this library, it's always null and my app crashes. I tried creating a test project in Swift and used the cocoa pod for this and everything works fine there. There's nothing of significance in the debug output, just that the singleton instance is null.

Any pointers to get this working?

Comment: Can you provide a sample which can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Here's a sample of the code from the ApiDefinition-  
 `[BaseType(typeof(NSObject), Name = "_TtC9Qualtrics9Qualtrics")]
    [DisableDefaultCtor]
    interface Qualtrics
    {
        // @property (readonly, nonatomic, strong, class) Qualtrics * _Nonnull shared;
        [Static]
        [Export("shared", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
        Qualtrics Shared { get; }`

Comment: Can't find out the cause with these codes.

Comment: @Tara did you find solution for this? I am facing with same problem since iOS 13

Comment: Sorry, I can't recollect what I did to fix it, but I was able to get it working. I think there might've been a conflict in some of the method names that I was using and the ones in the binding.